# Manual jobs available in some branches, but blocked in other ones

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

There are three main stages defined in `.gitlab-ci.yml` file: `test`, `deploy_test` and `deploy_integration`. The first stage gets executed every time, meanwhile the other ones are split into main (`actual`) and alternative deployments.

The idea was to be able to deploy application to alternative test server and alternative integration server when changes get commited to any branch. And it works for any branch but the `dev` branch:

[image: Pipeline stages]

The configuration file (cut-offs were made for better clarity) looks this way:

```yaml
image: ubuntu:18.04

stages:
  - test
  - deploy_test
  - deploy_integration

test:
  stage: test
  when: always
  script:
    - echo "Hi test!"

deploy_test_actual:
  stage: deploy_test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "dev"'
      when: manual
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"'
      when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Hi!"

deploy_test_alternative:
  stage: deploy_test
  when: manual
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - echo "Hi!"

deploy_int_actual:
  stage: deploy_integration
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "dev"'
      when: manual
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"'
      when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Hi!"

deploy_int_alternative:
  stage: deploy_integration
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Hi!"
```

The question: how to unlock `deploy_int_*` jobs for `dev` branch?

Comment: I can't get what you're trying to achieve here. What do you mean with "how to unlock `deploy_int_*`" ?
If I understood correctly, you're trying to deploy on aternative server _only_ when you push on some branch _but_ `dev`. And you want to deploy on `int` server when you push on `dev` branch. Am I correct ?

Comment: The setup is correct for "other" branches, and I'd like to be able to deploy on `int` in case of `dev` branch actions as well. In other words, I'd like to have the "play" icons instead of "block" ones next to `deploy_int_*` jobs.

Comment: It's possibly because your `deploy_test_alternative` task has `allow_failure = True`. For your `dev` branch configuration, `deploy_int_*` task depends on the realization of _all_ your `deploy_test_*` tasks, including `deploy_test_actual` which is not allowed to fail.

Comment: I tested it without `allow_failure` set up at all and the behavior is the same: `deploy_int_*` jobs appear as blocked, `deploy_test_*` have the option to be run manually.

Comment: Try with `allow_failure` set to `True` on both `deploy_test_alternative` _and_ `deploy_test_actual`.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Please add it as the answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `dev` branch configuration, `deploy_int_*` task depends on the realization of *all* your `deploy_test_*` tasks, including `deploy_test_actual` which is not allowed to fail.

On any other branch, `deploy_test_alternative` is the only task in your `deploy_test` stage. Because this task is allowed to fail (**`allow_failure=true`**), you can manually launch any `deploy_integration` task from Gitlab UI.

I would consider updating your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file :

```
deploy_test_actual:
  stage: deploy_test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "dev"'
      when: manual
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"'
      when: manual
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - echo "Hi!"
```